# Drive cycle on 2001 Saab 95 with codes P1312 & P1110

Tags: emissions, saab, 9-5, p1110

I replaced DIC, did a basic drive cycle to remove codes, but didn't remove codes. All my monitors are in ready state. The check engine lite was on, however, now it's off, I still show codes on scanner. O'Reilly's Auto Parts will not clear codes at this point, says do drive cycle. What am I doing wrong? Thank you

Comment: Please edit your question and stop YELLING at everyone!

Comment: Is your car a Saab 95 or a Saab 9-5 ... I'm pretty sure you mean a 9-5, so put that in the tags.

Answer (score 1):

This sounds like proper OBD-II software behavior.  The CARB OBD-II rules state that for most trouble codes the check engine light should go off after two passed tests and then the codes should erase from memory after 40 passed tests. 
The fact that the light has gone off on its own is a good sign that the repairs were correct. No need to clear the codes, just let the on board software resolve the issue.

Note that OBD software logic has changed over time so it is important to know what year the vehicle was made.  In the first few years, 96-98, it was not uncommon for the software to not follow the rules.

Comment: THANKS FRED, I TRIED ERASING MY CODES AND IT DID ERASE CODES, HOWEVER IT ALSO ERASED MY CATALYST MONITOR, EVAP. MONITOR,  AND O2 SENSORS, AND I RECEIVED YOUR SUGGESTION AFTER MY ERASE, TOMORROW I'LL CLOSE THE REST OF THE MONITORS AND O2S'. MY SCANNER SOUNDED AS IF THE CODES WOULD BE THE ONLY ITEMS ERASED. THANKS AGAIN

Comment: I suggest you not use the clear command. It clears many things. Just drive the car and let the onboard software runs it tests. If the CEL does not come back on in the next few trips you are done.   And turn your caps lock off.

Comment: FRED, IT STILL HAS NOT RESET CODE P1110, AND CEL IS ON, DO I CHANGE VACUUM VALVE?